# How to remove automatic margin I searched it on the internet but every page says margin:0 but that doesnt work for me

Tags: margin

The margin doesnt want to be removed idk what to do margin:0 doesn't work thanks for helping
[mypage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8sew.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use reset.css in every project.

Create a new css file like reset.css and add in your project
In that css file, save this css:
Reference: https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}


table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```